# if statement not working right?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I've looked and looked with the debugger and cannot seem to figure out why the IF statement always prints the message.

The IF statement checks to see if yesno != 'Y' ||(or) 'N'
but regardless if i type y or Y or n N or H B it will show... . Im not sure what move to make anymore! I cant seem to find where its going wrong?

```
if(yesno != 'Y' || 'N') { ...
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: The pastebin link does not appear to be working. As your problem seems to revolve around a single if statement why not just include this in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `||` doesn't quite mean what you think it means. The correct approach is:

```
if (yesno != 'Y' && yesno != 'N') { ...
```

This evaluates each side of the `&&` independently, and the result is true if *both* sides are true.

Note that

```
if (yesno != 'Y' || yesno != 'N') { ...
```

will *always* be true because any given character is *either* not Y *or* it is not N. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: But *why* doesn't it work as expected? +1 for pointing out the tautology. I think it's easier to see with D.M. as: `!(yesno == 'Y' && yesno == 'N')`.

Comment: if (yesno != 'Y' && yesno != 'N')

worked perfectly.... thanks, I had a brain fart there.... because as some one stated earlier i used it correctly on line 44... 

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
if(yesno != 'Y' || 'N')
```

should be:

```
if(yesno != 'Y' && yesno != 'N')
```

You are chaining them which is incorrect. I am fairly sure you know that you should not and that is a typo, because you used `&&` correctly on line no `44`.

Comment: @Als - Even though it is an improvement, it still always evaluates to  true. It is unclear if you mean he should use `&&` here as well.

Answer (score 2):

Take the conditional `yesno != 'Y' || 'N'` apart.  It has two clauses:

1. `yesno != 'Y'`.  This is probably a comparison you intended; it checks to see if the char `yesno` is inequal to the value `'Y'`.
2. `'N'`.  This clause evaluates simply to the value `'N'`.  As a bool, `'N'`, which is not zero, is considered "true."

So you have "(stuff) `||` (always true)".  Here  "stuff" is `yesno != 'Y'` and "always true" is `'N'`.  The result will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot OR an expression (yesno!='Y') and a statement ("N") which is also an expression. its only two or more expressions that can be combined using || and && to get the required output.

```
if(yesno!="Y"||"N")
```

is actually

```
if(yesno!="Y" || TRUE)
```

which is always true because:

```
Exp||TRUE=TRUE
```

regardless of the expression.

```
use if(yesno!="Y"|| yesno!="N")      // and in this case its && and not || i think
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put

> if (yesno != 'Y' || yesno != 'N')

You always need to put the full expression twice.

Comment: But it still always evaluates to true, as the variable cannot be both Y and N  at the same time.