# how do you change arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

help! im trying to replace 'a' and 'e' with ' ' in my array but it keeps replacing all of the array instead.

```
    for(int x = 0; x < array_length); x++)
    { 
      if(city_name[x] == 'a' || 'e')
        city_name[x] = " ";
    }
```

Comment: Turn up the warning level on the compiler. (Edit: [wtf](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12afbf0bee8132bb))

Comment: possible duplicate of [if statement not working right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170999/if-statement-not-working-right)

Comment: Use `city_name[x] = ' ';` instead of `city_name[x] = " ";`

Comment: If statement gets true value always due to `city_name[x] == 'a' || 'e'` this is like `whatever value here || 'e'` and 'e' is non false so final value is 'e' i.e true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(city_name[x] == 'a' || 'e')
```

should be

```
if(city_name[x] == 'a' || city_name[x] == 'e')
```

Your code is equivalent to

```
if( ( city_name[x] == 'a' ) || 'e')
```

which does `city_name[x] == 'a'` and then checks the `result of that statement || 'e'`

Comment: `==` has higher precedence than `||`

Comment: Ya, my mistake. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the loop is wrong. it contains a typo

```
for(int x = 0; x < array_length); x++)
                              ^^^
```

Remove the redundant parenthesis.

Also this condition

```
city_name[x] == 'a' || 'e'
```

is always equal to `true` because it is equivalent to

```
( city_name[x] == 'a'  ) || 'e'
```

And instead of string literal `" "` you have to use character literal `' '`

The correct loop can look like

```
for ( int i = 0; i < array_length; i++ )
{ 
    if ( city_name[i] == 'a' || city_name[i] == 'e' ) city_name[i] = ' ';
}
```

Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::replace_if` declared in header `<algorithm>` that can be used instead of the loop. For example

```
std::replace_if( city_name, city_name + array_length,
                 []( char c ) { return c == 'a' || c == 'e'; },
                 ' ' );
```